# Yandex.xml api to search for images only

Tags: xml, image, search, yandex

Is there a way to use Yandex.xml (search api) to find images instead of websites.
I tried several combinations with their rest get call:

https://yandex.com/search/xml?user=xxx&key=xxx&query=test&l10n=en&sortby=tm.order%3Dascending&filter=strict&groupby=attr%3D%22%22.mode%3Dflat.groups-on-page%3D10.docs-in-group%3D1

including 
https://yandex.com/**images**/search/xml?... but can only get back websites.

Comment: It can apparently be done using Google. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#isSampleQueries